# Smart pointer's with classes, Where does it points to?

Tags: c++, class, smart-pointers

I got this class (From my previous question, i just changed some stuff):

```
class Tree{
private:
    shared_ptr<Tree> Left;
    shared_ptr<Tree> Right;
    int Info;
public:
    Tree() :Info(0) ,Left(nullptr), Right(nullptr) {};
    Tree(int num) : Info(num), Left(nullptr) , Right(nullptr){};
    Tree& operator=(const Tree &src);
    void SetLeft(int num){Left.reset(new Tree(num));};
    void SetRight(int num){Right.reset(new Tree(num));};
    void SetInfo(int num){Info = num;};
    Tree GetLeft(){return *Left;};
    Tree GetRight(){return *Right;};
    int GetInfo(){return Info;};
};
Tree& Tree::operator=(const Tree &src){
    Left = src.Left;
    Right = src.Right;
    Info = src.Info;
    return *this;
}
```

This class create a tree that have 2 leaves `Left` and `Right` (Which have the class tree as well but in shared_ptr).

So i did this:

```
Tree tr(75);
tr.SetLeft(5);
tr.GetLeft().SetLeft(7);
tr.SetRight(3);
tr.GetRight().SetRight(1);
```

and when i try to cout the Left->Left or Right->Right `Info` (Which is the value of each tree):

```
cout << tr.GetRight().GetRight().GetInfo();
```

I get a weird error, something about the smart pointers (about the `reset` function), the compiler created a break point right here:

```
void _Reset(const _Ptr_base<_Ty2>& _Other)
    {   // release resource and take ownership of _Other._Ptr
    _Reset(_Other._Ptr, _Other._Rep);
    }
```

What did i do wrong?
thanks! :)

---

## EDIT:

I tried to check maybe it's because the `nullptr` and i compiled this:

```
shared_ptr<int> i;
int ib=6;
i=nullptr;
i.reset(&ib);
cout << *i;
```

After the program compiled i got an error from nowhere `"Debug Assertion Failed!"`.
I dont think its connected to my problem but what caused that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the cause of that particular error, but this will bite you eventually:

```
Tree GetLeft(){return *Left;};
```

returns a *copy* of Left. You want to return a reference:

```
Tree& GetLeft(){return *Left;}
```

(also notice no semicolon after `}`)

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
class Tree{
...
    Tree GetLeft(){return *Left;};
    Tree GetRight(){return *Right;};
...
};
```

**creates copies** of the left and right trees respectively on return.
This means that the following statements:

```
tr.GetLeft().SetLeft(7);
tr.GetRight().SetRight(1);
```

set the left and right trees of **temporary copies** of the 'tr' tree's left and right children, respectively.
You can test this easily with the following assertion (assuming that access to Left and Right is allowed in the current context), which will fail, since the address of a **temporary copy** of a given subtree is compared with the address of the original subreee:

```
assert(&tr.GetLeft() == &tr.Left.get());
assert(&tr.GetRight() == &tr.Right.get());
```

The correct version should be:

```
class Tree{
...
    Tree& GetLeft(){return *Left;}
    Tree& GetRight(){return *Right;}
...
};
```

as you want to return a **reference to the actual subtree object**, instead of a copy.
Using this version, your code should run as you expect it it to, and the assertions above will not fail.